# Kotlin wait until function ends

Tags: kotlin, httprequest

I am doing a http request but I need to return a value if I got answer or not. 
My problem is that my code continues and my http request has not finished.
But I all always get false because function is returning before http request ends
I am using Fuel library

Thanks
Something like this:

```
fun get_data():Boolean{
 val URL:String="http:myurl"
 var response:Boolean=false

URL.httpGet( listOf("user" to "user")).responseJson{request, response, result ->

                result.fold(
                        success = { json ->

                            response=true

                        },
                        failure = { error ->
                            response=false
                        }
                )

            }

return response

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using Fuel library the [Async mode](https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel#async-mode) , what you should use is the [Blocking mode](https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel#blocking-mode) .

something like this

```
val (request, response, result) = URL.httpGet().responseJson()
```